# Get the "value" from a ComboBox dropdown item?

Tags: .net, powershell

Trying to store a collection of information in a microsoft combobox dropdown item, so that when it's selected, you can pull those values out (similar to react etc.) Is this possible?

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$combo = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$combo.Items.add("test")

#get value of selected item here (this code does not work)
write-output($combo.Items[$combo.SelectedIndex].value)
```

In this example:

```
$DBArray = Get-Content "$Global:DashboardDir\IncludeFiles\Datapools\Tables\Tables.txt"
#Setup Table Dropdown
foreach ($Database in $DBArray) {
    $info = $database.split("|")
    if ($Database -ne 'SQLServer|DBName|TableName') {
        $SelectQueryCDC_Tables.Items.add(@{
                value   = $info
                display = "CDC Enabled for $($info[2])?"
            })
    }
}
```

which displays:
[image]

I would like to store the full $info array as a value somewhere so that I can manipulate it later, whilst still only displaying the `display` property.

Comment: @RufusL ah yes sorry, tags have been updated

Comment: Close - `$combo.Items[$combo.SelectedIndex]`. No need for a property. The Items property is just a collection of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove the `.value` property accessor:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $combo.Items[$combo.SelectedIndex]
test
```

This is because the `Items` property is a collection of objects, and there is no `value` property on an object:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $combo.Items.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
False    False    ObjectCollection                         System.Object

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $combo.Items[$combo.SelectedIndex].GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

---

Now that you've updated your question to indicate that you're adding hastables to the collection, you can use the key of the item in the hashtable that you want to display:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$combo = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$combo.Items.add(@{
    value   = "the info array would be here"
    display = "CDC Enabled display message here"
})

#show the display message of the selected item here
write-output($combo.Items[$combo.SelectedIndex]['display'])
```

You can read more about how to use hashtables here: [Everything you wanted to know about hashtables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-hashtable?view=powershell-7.2)

---

Ok, with the latest edit to the question, it appears that you're missing two things:

1. use a `[PSCustomObject]` type for the item being added to the combobox
2. set the `DisplayMember` property of the combobox to the property that you want to show

For example:

```
foreach ($database in $DBArray) {
    $info = $database.split("|")

    if ($database -ne 'SQLServer|DBName|TableName') {
        $combo.Items.add([PSCustomObject]@{
                value   = $info
                display = "CDC Enabled for $($info[2])?"
            })
    }
}

$combo.DisplayMember = 'display'
```

Comment: Sorry for notification spam if you see it, was having issues formatting a comment, Would you mind checking the updated question to see my extended example and explain how I could use the object to display that? thank you in advance

Comment: For instance if I set it to an object: `@{value = $info display = "CDC Enabled for $($info[2])?})"`
How would I still make it only display the `display` property in this instance

Comment: Please don't change one question into another. Mark one as resolved (if it is) and then ask a new question. If your edit is to clarify the question, then I'm afraid I don't understand what you're asking. Are you asking how to save the `info` array for later?

Comment: Yes, by using the object that you explained, I'm wondering how to store the `info` array as it's "value" the initital question, while still displaying the `display` property to the user instead of `System.Collections.Hashtable`.

Comment: Sorry, this is confusing. Initially you were talking about a combobox items collection. Now you're talking about a string array, which is very different. Also, the code shows opening a "tables" file, yet the variable name indicates "databases". Not sure what you mean by `display` property or "value" in the comment above, nor do I know where `Hashtable` comes into the question. Can you please simplify the question? What precisely are you asking?

Comment: If i have an item, (now as an object after your suggestion, updated question to reflect this) how can I display 1 property of that item (display prop), while storing another (the info array).

Comment: Oh, I see, you're using a hashtable to store them. I updated the answer with how to access an item in a hashtable using it's key.

Comment: Sorry, I feel like this is my fault for not explaining clearly, I know how to access the information now that it's in a hashtable. But how it is actually displayed in the powershell gui still as `System.Collections.Hashtable` I'm not sure how to fix. Please let me know if I need to open a new question for this.